# Retrieving values from URL in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

My URL is:

`http://localhost/working/myapp/login/index/user_id=&user_email=shashankbhat11%40gmail.com&sig=%C3%86%C3%B1z%C3%BD-o6%C2%B6%01%C2%8A%C3%81%C2%A6%C2%A7z%C2%A1%C3%962%3E:%C3%83F%C2%90M%C2%99%C3%BD%C3%A7%C2%A1O%18%C3%83F%3E`

How to retrieve user_email and sig values only from this URl in codeigniter controller, i tried this

```html
        $var1 = $this->uri->segment(4);
        echo $user_email;
        die;
```

and it is giving me an output as below,

> user_id=&user_email=shashankbhat11%40gmail.com&sig=%C3%86%C3%B1z%C3%BD-o6%C2%B6%01%C2%8A%C3%81%C2%A6%C2%A7z%C2%A1%C3%962%3E:%C3%83F%C2%90M%C2%99%C3%BD%C3%A7%C2%A1O%18%C3%83F%3E

but I need only the value of `user_email` i.e `shashankbhat11%40gmail.com` in the variables `var1` and `var2` variable should contain `%C3%86%C3%B1z%C3%BD-o6%C2%B6%01%C2%8A%C3%81%C2%A6%C2%A7z%C2%A1%C3%962%3E:%C3%83F%C2%90M%C2%99%C3%BD%C3%A7%C2%A1O%18%C3%83F%3E` which is the `sig` part.

Comment: after your `login/index` there is no `?` and  `login/index/?user_id` etc but if function index your calling you do not need to include index in url `login/?user_id`

Comment: You have no segment #4... even if your URL was properly constructed, [as per docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment), the segments are numbered from left to right starting after `index.php`

Comment: Please do no tag-spam... you cannot be using version 2 and 3 of CodeIgniter at the same time.  Also, if the Code-Snippets feature was meant for PHP, then there would be a box labeled "PHP".  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $var1 = $this->input->get('user_email');
    echo $user_email;
    die;
```

Comment: have you tested by replacing `/` by `?` after `index`??

Comment: yes, still the page is blank, i dont know if its working or not

Comment: redirect('http://localhost/working/myapp/login/index?'.'user_id='.$user->id.
    '?user_email='.urlencode($email).
    '?sig='.$sig, 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

The the specified URL is not formatted correctly. You need to put "?" in the URL to access URL values as get. See the question mark in the URL below.

```
http://localhost/working/myapp/login/index/?user_id=&user_email=shashankbhat11%40gmail.com&sig=%C3%86%C3%B1z%C3%BD-o6%C2%B6%01%C2%8A%C3%81%C2%A6%C2%A7z%C2%A1%C3%962%3E:%C3%83F%C2%90M%C2%99%C3%BD%C3%A7%C2%A1O%18%C3%83F%3E
```

Once you formatted the URL you can use below code to access it:

```
$user_id = $this->input->get('user_id');
$user_email = $this->input->get('user_email');
```

Comment: not working.. gives a blank page, my redirect looks like this,redirect('http://localhost/working/myapp/login/index?'.'user_id='.$user->id.
    '?user_email='.urlencode($email).
    '?sig='.$sig, 'refresh');

Comment: Your URL is again wrong i think. Why you putting `?` before `?sig=`.  See codeigniter documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::get